# Do I need a comma before "and" or is the other "and" necessary for this sentence?

Tags: punctuation

Do I need a comma before "and" or is the other "and" necessary for this sentence?

> I interviewed people and filmed with a DSLR camera and edited videos in iMovie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I interviewed people and filmed with a DSLR camera and edited videos in iMovie.

This sentence is grammatically correct as it is, but it sounds a little breathless and close to being a run-on sentence. It is as if you haven't figured out what you're going to say when you start the sentence. You can make it into a clearer list by replacing all "and"s but the last one with commas:

> I interviewed people, filmed with a DSLR camera and edited videos in iMovie.

You may choose to use a comma before the final "and;" that is the [Oxford comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma):

> I interviewed people, filmed with a DSLR camera, and edited videos in iMovie.

No matter what you do, saying you "filmed with a DSLR camera" is a little awkward because "to film *with*" generally wants to take a direct object. If you don't want an object it might be better to choose a verb like "operated."

Comment: Thank you! I can instead say, I interviewed and filmed people using a DSLR camera and edited video footage in iMovie.

Comment: Yes, that is quite a different sentence altogether! In the first sentence there is no grammatical connection between "interviewing people" and "filming" (thought you might imagine an intended connection). By grouping "interviewing and filming" together you can make both verbs apply to "people" and the connection is made clear.